# Stack Overflow and Super User icons for use in Windows 7's taskbar with Prism

Tags: support, stack-overflow, images, superuser, logo

I use Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault every day, so I have them pinned to my Windows 7 taskbar with [Prism](https://mozillalabs.com/prism/), a web application that lets you use websites like they're normal Windows applications. It's like the "application shortcut" feature in Chrome, but with more customisation options.

The default icons (the sites' `favicon`s) are very low quality when used in the taskbar, though Server Fault's looks okay because of the logo's design. I have been able to find high quality icons for Gmail, [Remember The Milk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remember_the_Milk) and other sites I use through Prism. Are there high-quality (i.e. larger dimension-wise) `.ICO` files available for SO and SU with the logo and no text?

Gmail icon example (I used the `.ICO` in the packaged download): [From deviant art](http://ncrow.deviantart.com/art/Icon-Gmail-121223675)

Comment: By high quality do you mean larger dimensions?

Comment: Yes, the SO and SU icons are very pixelated compared to icons I have found for other sites.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not `.ico`, but you can try the `PNG` type icons they have showing for those bookmarking on the iPhone and similar:

> [image: apple touch icon for stack overflow]
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png

♥

> [image: apple touch icon for server fault]
>
> https://serverfault.com/content/serverfault/img/apple-touch-icon.png

♣

> [image: apple touch icon for super user]
>
> https://superuser.com/content/superuser/img/apple-touch-icon.png

♠

> [image: apple touch icon for meta]
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png

And you can get the general idea for the other sites:

> [image: toke on a toque]
>
> https://cooking.stackexchange.com/content/cooking/img/apple-touch-icon.png

Comment: Thanks very much.  I grabbed a program called IcoFx, did a quick import and export of the images you gave me and they look great.

Comment: @James The links are still working

Comment: Apple touch icon??

Comment: @random Links are not working

Answer (score 6):

The SVG source, as well as an archive containing icon-sized versions, is posted on [this Stack Apps post](https://stackapps.com/q/347):

[image: StackExchange]
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/stackexchange.png
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/stackexchange.svg

[image: StackOverflow]
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/stackoverflow.png
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/stackoverflow.svg

[image: Superuser]
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/superuser.png
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/superuser.svg

[image: Serverfault]
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/serverfault.png
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/serverfault.svg

[image: Meta StackOverflow]
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/meta.png
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/meta.svg

[image: StackApps]
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/stackapps.png
http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/images/stackapps.svg

Be sure to check the rules before using these. The OP is OK, others who download should be careful: https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance

Comment: Hey... that's *my* website! Thanks for posting those.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison - I didn't realize that!  Do you mind if I link to the PNGs on your site?  I inserted the embedded images via the uploader, so they're on imgur, which should be able handle the bandwidth more cheaply.

Comment: Not at all! Go right ahead, and thanks for telling people about these icons. I made them last year and almost forgot about them.