# Imprints/logos for the sites

Tags: feature-request, images, logo

I'm looking for an imprint/logo/whatever to use in order to link to online profiles in a site I'm working on.

I noticed that [careers.stackoverflow.com](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/) has a [logo image](https://web.archive.org/web/20091115155940if_/http://careers.stackoverflow.com/content/cso/img/logo.png) with a white background while the [superuser](https://superuser.com/) [logo](https://sstatic.net/su/img/logo.png) doesn't.

Would it be too much to ask to have a page devoted to imprints (in various forms, PNG, vector, etc) or at least strip the background off of the others?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/what-are-the-rules-on-using-the-stack-overflow-logo

Comment: More images for you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32755/apple-icons

Comment: Still meta and SO have that border around the image while SU / SF don't. It just looks out of place on the page when I lay it out.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the logos are copyrighted as you'll note in the footer...

> site design and logo is © 2010 stackoverflow.com llc

... so we tend to want to control how our logos are used when it comes to hi-res versions, as that implies some kind of product creation that we may or may not endorse.